# Script not working properly when page refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the code of a scroll to top button as you can see at [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0d5188ry/) The problem with the code is that at the time the page is loaded the button is displayed (which it should not, it should be displayed when the person scrolls below). Once scrolled down, on scrolling up the issue no longer prevails, the button vanishes at the top as it should. Refreshing the page again would let us see the button again without any scrolling down.

Since I am a javascript noob, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
<div class="scroll-top" style="display: block;">
   <img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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" />
  <span class="flame"></span>
  <span class="flame"></span>
  <span class="flame"></span>
</div>

<style>
.scroll-top img{
  height:45px;
  margin: -12px 0 0 5px;
  border:0;
}
.scroll-top {height: 60px; width: 60px; position: fixed; bottom: 100px; right: 30px; display: none; z-index: 9999;}.scroll-top:hover{animation-delay:0s;animation-duration:.1s;animation-iteration-count:infinite;animation-name:shake-little;animation-play-state:running;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}.scroll-top .flame{-moz-border-bottom-colors:none;-moz-border-left-colors:none;-moz-border-right-colors:none;-moz-border-top-colors:none;border-color:#ffda44 transparent transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:25px 3px 3px;display:none;height:0;left:-4px;margin:-5px auto 0;position:absolute;right:0;top:66%;width:0}.scroll-top .flame+.flame{border-width:10px 2px 2px;left:20px;margin:0}.scroll-top .flame+.flame+.flame{border-width:10px 2px 2px;left:auto;margin:0;right:24px}.scrolling .flame{display:block}.nav-toggle,.owl-item .quote-icon,.price-box .price-box-head-shadow,.scroll-top .flame{transition:all .5s cubic-bezier(.25,.1,.25,1) 0s}@keyframes shake-little{0%{transform:translate(0,0) rotate(0)}14%,16%,2%,20%,24%,30%,48%,52%,54%,76%,8%,84%,86%,88%,92%,96%,98%{transform:translate(0,0) rotate(-.5deg)}10%,12%,22%,32%,4%,42%,44%,64%,72%,80%,90%{transform:translate(-1px,0) rotate(-.5deg)}18%,34%,36%,46%,6%,66%,68%,70%,74%,82%,94%{transform:translate(0,-1px) rotate(-.5deg)}26%,28%,38%,40%,50%,56%,58%,60%,62%,78%{transform:translate(-1px,-1px) rotate(-.5deg)}}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Scroll to top button
    wnHeight = jQuery(window).height();
    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > wnHeight/2) {
            jQuery('.scroll-top').fadeIn();
        } else {
            jQuery('.scroll-top').fadeOut().removeClass('scrolling');
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    jQuery('.scroll-top').click(function(){
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        jQuery(this).addClass('scrolling');
    });

</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just change the display style property of `div.scroll-top` to none by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the button with `display: none` (in CSS) and it doesn't how at the start of the script

```
.scroll-top { display: none; }
```

Then it works with your javascript code.

See it working: https://jsfiddle.net/0d5188ry/2/

Comment: But you have `<div class="scroll-top" style="display: block;">` overriding that property, Remove the `style` in this tag

Comment: Oh how did I missed that. Thanks a lot :)